# How to linearize a max function about a small change??

Tags: calculus, linear-programming, perturbation-theory, linearization, linear-approximation

My question is the following:

Given a vector field $\mathbf{v}$, we have the following functional: $f\{\mathbf{v}\}=1/|\mathbf{v}|_{\text{max}}$, where $|\mathbf{v}|_\text{max}$ is the maximum of the 2-norm of the vector field $\mathbf{v}$ over $\Omega$ (where $\Omega$ is the domain of interest, which is bounded).  Now lets assume we perturb the vector field slightly: $\mathbf{v}\rightarrow\mathbf{v}+\Delta{\mathbf{v}}$, where $|\Delta \mathbf{v}|\ll |\mathbf{v}|_{\text{max}}$ over $\Omega$.  To lowest order, $f\{\mathbf{v+\Delta\mathbf{v}}\}\sim1/|\mathbf{v}|_\text{max}$ .

My question is:  what would the first order correction term be (i.e. first order in $\Delta\mathbf{v}$)??

(Additional assumptions include that both $\mathbf{v}$ and $\Delta\mathbf{v}$ are smooth and continuous, and remain bounded in $\Omega$)

Thanks.

Comment: If $\mathbf{v}$ assumes its maximum value on a subset $\Omega' \subseteq \Omega$, then the first-order correction to $|\mathbf{v}|_{\text {max}}$ would be the maximum value of $(\mathbf{v} / |\mathbf{v}|_{\text {max}}) \cdot \Delta \mathbf{v}$ over $\Omega'$.

Comment: Am I right to assume that by finite you mean bounded?

Comment: Yes, I mean bounded (for $\Omega$)

Comment: I guess I am looking for a linearization that removes a non-linearity.  Having a maximum over a function involving $\Delta \mathbf{v}$ seems to me to still be inherently non-linear.

Comment: But maybe that is the best that can be done.

Comment: I don't know about the maximum, but for fixed vectors $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf u$ with $\lVert\mathbf u\rVert$ small, we have $$\frac{1}{\lVert\mathbf v+\mathbf u\rVert}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathbf v^2+2\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf u+\mathbf u^2}}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathbf v^2+2\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf u}}$$ $$=\frac{1}{\lVert\mathbf v\rVert}\left(1+2\frac{\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf u}{\mathbf v^2}\right)^{-1/2}\approx\frac{1}{\lVert\mathbf v\rVert}\left(1-\frac{\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf u}{\mathbf v^2}\right)$$ by the binomial formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found an answer to my own question.  Thoughts/comments would be appreciated however.

So if we assume that $\Delta \mathbf{v}$ is sufficiently small in magnitude, (but still an arbitrary perturbation), then we can expand the max functional to first order in $\Delta \mathbf{v}$.

We first define the max functional as $$\text{max}\{f\}\equiv\cfrac{\underset{\Omega}{\int} \text{d}^3 x fe^{\alpha f}}{\underset{\Omega}{\int} \text{d}^3 x e^{\alpha f}}\ ,\tag{1}\label{1}$$ where $\alpha$ is a very large number.  We will also for convenience define $G\{f\}\equiv \underset{\Omega}{\int} \text{d}^3 x fe^{\alpha f}$ and $H\{f\}\equiv \underset{\Omega}{\int} \text{d}^3 x e^{\alpha f}$.   In other words, $$\text{max}\{f\}=\cfrac{G\{f\}}{H\{f\}} \tag{2}\label{2}\ .$$.

If we expand both $G\{f\}$ and $H\{f\}$, each as a zeroth-order and first-order contribution in $\Delta \mathbf{v}$, and then expand the denominator of Eq. (\ref{2}), Eq. (\ref{2}) becomes: $$\text{max}\{f\}\approx\cfrac{G_0}{H_0}+\cfrac{G_1}{H_0}-\cfrac{G_0H_1}{H_0^2}\ ,\tag{3}\label{3}$$ where subscripts refer to the order of the terms in the expansions for $G$ and $H$ respectively. All we then have left to do is find the first order contributions to $G$ and $H$ (i.e. $G_1$ and $H_1$).

We first note that $|\mathbf{v}+\Delta \mathbf{v}|\approx |\mathbf{v}|+(\mathbf{v}\cdot\Delta \mathbf{v})/{|\mathbf{v}}|$ , where we have expanded the input to the functionals into a zeroth-order term and a first-order term. Using this, we Taylor-expand the integrand in each functional about $\mathbf{v}$: $$G_1\{\mathbf{v},\Delta \mathbf{v}\}=\underset{\Omega}{\int}\text{d}^3 x (1+\alpha |\mathbf{v}|)e^{\alpha |\mathbf{v}|}\left(\cfrac{\mathbf{v}\cdot\Delta \mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}\right)\ ,$$ and $$H_1\{\mathbf{v},\Delta \mathbf{v}\}=\underset{\Omega}{\int}\text{d}^3 x \alpha e^{\alpha |\mathbf{v}|}\left(\cfrac{\mathbf{v}\cdot\Delta \mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}\right)\ .$$ If we define the $x$ value at which the maximum of $|\mathbf{v}|$ occurs to be $x_{\text{max}}$, then it is easily seen that: $$\cfrac{G_0}{H_0}=|\mathbf{v}|_\text{max}\ ,$$ $$\cfrac{G_1}{H_0}=\left.\left[(1+\alpha |\mathbf{v}|)\left(\cfrac{\mathbf{v}\cdot\Delta \mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}\right)\right]\right|_{x_\text{max}}\ ,$$ and $$-\cfrac{G_0H_1}{H_0^2}=-|\mathbf{v}|_\text{max}\alpha\left.\left(\cfrac{\mathbf{v}\cdot\Delta \mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}\right)\right|_{x_{\text{max}}}\ .$$

Plugging the above three results into Eq. (\ref{3}), we obtain that $$\text{max}\{|\mathbf{v}+\Delta \mathbf{v}|\}\approx |\mathbf{v}|_\text{max}+\left.\left(\cfrac{\mathbf{v}\cdot\Delta \mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}\right)\right|_{x_\text{max}}\ .$$  From this, we obtain the final result: $$\cfrac{1}{\text{max}\{|\mathbf{v}+\Delta \mathbf{v}|\}}\approx \cfrac{1}{|\mathbf{v}|_\text{max}}-\left.\left(\cfrac{\mathbf{v}\cdot\Delta \mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|^3}\right)\right|_{x_\text{max}}\ .$$

This is a linear expansion, because $x_\text{max}$ does not depend on $\Delta \mathbf{v}$.

This analysis assumes that there is only one $x_\text{max}$ .  If there are multiple $x_\text{max}$, and using the same above analysis, it can be shown that $$\cfrac{1}{\text{max}\{|\mathbf{v}+\Delta \mathbf{v}|\}}\approx \cfrac{1}{|\mathbf{v}|_\text{max}}-\left(\cfrac{\mathbf{v}\cdot\Delta \mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|^3}\right)_\text{ave}\ ,$$ where $()_\text{ave}$ is the average value of the quantity over all the $x_\text{max}$ in $\Omega$.